# Задачка по информатике 11 класс (средний балл)

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада, информатика

Ученик 10 класса учился по математике без двоек, при этом его средний
годовой балл по предмету составил 4,2. Если бы у него было троек столько,
сколько он получил пятерок, четверок столько, сколько он получил троек, а
пятерок столько, сколько он получил четверок, то его средний годовой балл
составил бы 4,24. Сколько было четверок у ученика, если всего за год он
получил не более 110 оценок.
На выходе: одно число.

Comment: В задаче нет информации об одиницах. Поэтому вполне может быть, что задача просто на внимание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> учился по математике без двоек, при этом его средний годовой балл по
> предмету составил 4,2

Пусть ученик получил X троек, Y четверок и Z пятерок, тогда средний балл у него был бы

```
(3X + 4Y + 5Z) / (X + Y + Z) = 4.2
```

Из условия задачи известно, что

> Если бы у него было троек столько, сколько он получил пятерок,
> четверок столько, сколько он получил троек, а пятерок столько, сколько
> он получил четверок, то его средний годовой балл составил бы 4,24

т.е.

```
(3Z + 4X + 5Y) / (X + Y + Z) = 4.24
```

> за год он получил не более 110 оценок.

т.е.

```
X + Y + Z <= 110
```

Из первых двух уравнений можно составить вырожденную систему линейных арифметических уравнений

А с помощью еще и неравенства можно получить систему линейных арифметических неравенств, где у нас одна из выбранных переменных будет лежать в некотором диапазоне и программа должна всего лишь этот диапазон перебрать и проверить целочисленные решения системы

Comment: Нехорошо все же поощрять халявщиков...

Comment: @Harry, а разве я код давал? Эта задача вообще решается на бумаге без единой строчки программирования. Алгоритм я описал, дело человека - его реализовать

Comment: Без готового решения вполне приемлемо

Comment: Не более — это таки `<=`

Comment: @vp_arth, да, виноват, хотя все равно без разницы :) основная теорема арифметики не дает этим `=` воспользоваться :)

Кстати интересный вопрос - в таких задачах подразумевается ли математическое ручное предварительное решение для последующего перебора 4 значений :) или надо O(n^3) заделать?

Comment: Скорее всего не допускается, иначе все такие программы были бы просто выводом правильных ответов) Хотя, это же олимпиада? Там на код никто не смотрит.

Comment: Хм, решений многовато) [X=3k, Y=14k, Z=8k](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283X+%2B+4Y+%2B+5Z%29+%2F+%28X+%2B+Y+%2B+Z%29+%3D+4.2%3B+%283Z+%2B+4X+%2B+5Y%29+%2F+%28X+%2B+Y+%2B+Z%29+%3D+4.24%3B+%28X%2BY%2BZ%29+%3C%3D+100%3B+X+is+integer)

Comment: @vp_arth, про 3 условие то не забывайте :) X=3,6,9,12 и всё, все остальные приводят к тому, что кол-во оценок превышает 110

Comment: Таки всё равно многовато для одного числа в ответе)